# Schema for a JSON object with varying index size

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, backend, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

Basically, I have a MEAN stack application where I want to define a schema where array size varies. I have been told that this is possible.

I have successfully saved a JSON object on MongoDB which looks like this;

```
{
    "Diseases":[
                {
                "DiseaseName": "Diabetes",
                "Severity": "3"
                
            },
                {
                "DiseaseName": "Psoriasis",
                "Severity": "4"
            }
        ],
    
  "Prescriptions": [
            {
                "Name" : "Insulin",
                "Unit" : "100 microgram"
            },
          {
            "Name" : "Cortisone",
            "Unit" : "150 microgram"
          }        
    ]       
}
```

Basically, I want to define a schema where the number of array elements (objects) in Diseases and Prescriptions could be arbitrary. If I have understood this correctly, Diseases and Prescriptions are array which contain objects enclosed within an object.

Comment: Could not get your question can you clarify it?  What you mean by saying arbitrary? should it be some constant number? or unlimited. If you don't want to limit the size of array it is set by mongoose, so you don't have to worry. Please be more specific while giving questions and one more note always read the documentation of your stack first,

Comment: Arbitrary means that there is no set number, it could by anything. For example, a patient could have any (or no disease at all!) number of diseases, similiar for prescriptions. I do not know how to write the schema in the back-end for this (usually in the patient.model.js)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample Schema you could use:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const diseaseSchema = new Schema({
    diseaseName:{               
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    severity: {
        type: Number,
        min:0,
        max: 5,
        required: true
    }
},{
    timestamps: true
});

const prescriptionSchema = new Schema({
    name:{               
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    unit: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
},{
    timestamps: true
});


const patientSchema = new Schema({
    diseases: [diseaseSchema]
    prescriptions: [prescriptionSchema]
},{
    timestamps: true
});

var Patients = mongoose.model('Patient', patientSchema);

module.exports = Patients;
```

For reference look into the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems you need a schema for arrays of objects in your database. Here is how you can do it.

```
 mongoose.Schema({
      Diseases: [
        {
          DiseaseName: String,
          Severity: Number,
        },
      ],
      Prescriptions: [
        {
          Name: String,
          Unit: String,
        },
      ],
    });
```